# asp:CustomValidator - user input is equal to a set parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I am not too familiar with custom validation. If you are willing to help, it is MUCH appreciated!

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valMatchUserInput" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbUserInput"  ErrorMessage="Please do something.">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Basically, if the user input does not match (is not equal to) a specific parameter, I would like an error message to display, so nothing happens until the user fixes the error.

Thanks!

Comment: Because you didn't include a validating function(You are not comparing yr parameter). Which is why the error is not firing.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example...

Let's say this is your validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valMatchUserInput" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbUserInput"  ErrorMessage="Please do something." **ClientValidationFunction="Bla_ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="Bla_ServerValidate"**>&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
```

You have to include a server-side validation and a client-side validation.

Code behind (server-side)

```
protected void Bla_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    //Compare your parameter here
}
```

Javascript (client-side)

```
function bla_ClientValidate(sender, e) {
// Compare your parameter here
```

}

It should work then